# Trying to plot real time data in plotly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code were i want to draw a live cahrt

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

style.use('fivethirtyeight')

# Create figure for plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
xs = []
ys = []


def animate(i, xs, ys):

    # Read temperature (Celsius) from TMP102
    polarity = open("sentiment2.txt", "r").read()
    lines = polarity.split('\n')
    print(lines)
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            x,y = line.split(',')
            xs.append(dt.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'))
            ys.append(line)
    # Add x and y to lists


    # Limit x and y lists to 20 items
    xs = xs[-20:]
    ys = ys[-20:]

    # Draw x and y lists
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(xs, ys)

    # Format plot
    plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)
    plt.title('Etehreum Sentiment')
    plt.ylabel('Sentiment')

# Set up plot to call animate() function periodically
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(xs, ys), interval=60000)
plt.show()
```

When i run it i get this error:

```
File "ploty.py", line 23, in animate
    x,y = line.split(',')

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I have this code from a tutorial and he does the same as i try to achieve so im not sure whats the problem here

What I try to achieve is to get the value(sentiment) from my text file- i run a senitment analysis every 10 minutes and whenever my sentiment.txt file gets updated i want to update my chart

the content of my sentiment.txt file:

```
-8.944388227513231
-7.731292989417991
-8.493252615440113
0.5413275613275612
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps look at how you had generated the `sentiment2.txt` file.

Each line of your `sentiment2.txt` file has only one number and there is no comma.
so despite the `line.split(',')`, there is only one of the coordinate but the code is expecting TWO, X AND Y.

*Updated:*
Currently, the chart is plotting xs and ys onto the chart; ys are values from the file and xs is the real-time when reading the value. If that is intended, then the split line is redundant and can be removed, and you can remove the 'commas' from your source file.

However, if the sentiment file should contains both x-axis and y-axis values; x and y should map into xs and ys instead:

```
x,y = line.split(',')
xs.append(x)
ys.append(y)
```

The latter can be improved further by working with panda which works with csv files see: [Plot from CSV with Plotly Express](https://plotly.com/python/plot-data-from-csv/)

Comment: I now generate my sentiment with a comma like this "34.00000," and it starts plotting, however i need to fix the style but this was the fix i did, do you know of a better way?

Comment: Noticed, x and y are not being used in your example code, so perhaps `x,y = line.split(',')` is redundant code from copy and pasting. See the updated answer.